# Formula for determining number of comparisons in a sort?

Tags: java, sorting, merge, selection, insertion

I'm curious if there's a formula/rule to find the total number of comparisons done in a sorting algorithm, particularly merge sort, selection sort, and insertion sort. I'm pretty sure with selection sort the rule is `n(n-1)/2`where n is the number of elements being sorted. I thought the same was the case for an insertion sort but apparently that's not true according to a practice Java test I took (with a list of 6 items the insertion sort makes 14 comparisons, according to the answer key, and 15 comparisons with a selection sort). So now I'm confused.

Comment: There is not. You could write a counting comparator and use that to test the two algorithms. Without seeing the implementations how would we know? Also, big oh notation is not a formula in the traditional sense.

Comment: Well I'm referring to if you were visualizing a selection sort/merge sort/insertion sort on paper. Using the principles behind each sorting algorithm, I'm sure there's a rule to finding the number of comparisons done between numbers. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I choose [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Number of comparisons is zero. There, that's a rule. From the link, *The counter argument is that comparison-based algorithms are measured in number of comparisons, not actual time complexity. Under some assumptions the comparisons will be constant time on average, under others they will not. Comparisons of randomly generated keys takes constant time on average, as keys differ on the very first bit in half the cases, and differ on the second bit in half of the remaining half, and so on*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are no precise formulae for a couple of reasons:

1. There is sufficient scope for variation in implementing various sort algorithms that there can be small discrepancies between different implementations of the same algorithm.
2. With some algorithms, the number of comparisons depend on the elements and their initial order.

And certainly, there is no "one size fits all" formula that covers all algorithms in (say) the same complexity class.

---

One clue: if a sort algorithm has a best case or worst case complexity that is different from its average complexity, then the number of comparisons or the number of moves depends on the inputs.